# Print rows containing word from all words in txt file

Tags: python

I have tab separated file with 57k rows and 23 columns containing words.

I want to print all rows from my large file which they contain word from my txt file.

My file with words:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
for l in file:
    lines = l.strip().split('\t')
```

Example output from file above:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

Now I want print all rows from my large .txt file with sentences such as:

```
Here aaa is a good day.
Your bbb is very good.
Here ccc.
```

How to do it?

Best

Comment: No clue what you’re asking, please elaborate on the question

Comment: @aws_apprentice I want to print all rows from my other large .txt file which contains each word from my txt file(57k rows and 23 columns)

Comment: that still makes no sense at all, there’s only one text file here being shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to find word intersection between two files. 
The easiest option is to use sets:

```
words = set()
for line in open("file.txt"):
    words.update(line.strip().split("\t"))

for line in open("sentences.txt"):
    stripline = line.strip()
    line_words = set(stripline.split(" "))
    intersection = line_words & words
    if intersection:
        print stripline
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understand the answare

```
rows=open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
rows=[a.split("\t") for a in rows]

for row in rows:
    print("here " + row + " is good day")
```

or, for search a word in all the row

```
lista=[]
word="parola"
rows=open('file.txt', 'r').readlines()
for row in rows:
    if word in row: lista.append(row.split("\t"))

for row in word:
    print("here " + row + " is good day")
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the words and then check their presence

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = []
    for l in f:
        words.extend(l.strip().split())

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for w in words:
            if w in line:
                print(line)
                break
```